# xp_cmdshell works only for absolute file paths?

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

I have a sql code as follows:

```
SET @FILEE = '..\mydb.sql';
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(1000);
SET @cmd = 'SQLCMD -S (local)\MYSQL -i' + @FILEE
exec xp_cmdshell @cmd;
```

This always gives an error: `SqlCmd:'..\mydb.sql': invalid filename.`

If I put in something like: `C:\mydb.sql`, it works....but not for a referenced filename like above..where the file path is mentioned with reference to the location of the current file.

Any pointers on how to work around this?

If not, is there a way to reference a vob location?

Answer (score 4):

`SQLCMD` will work with relative file paths when correctly specified - the problem you're hitting is that the working directory that `xp_cmdshell` starts in is not the directory you're expecting.

You can see the starting directory by running the following command:

```
xp_cmdshell 'cd'
```

By default I think this is normally the operating system `\system32` directory (typically `C:\Windows\system32`, but obviously this can vary depending on the details of the Windows installation)

Your workarounds are to specify an absolute path (as you have already discovered) or to use the `CD` command to switch to a different working directory from which the relative path you want to use is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Resurrecting an old thread in hopes it may help someone like me. I had a problem executing a script which in turn referenced other scripts via relative paths.

It is possible to chain commands in CMD.

Assuming you know what folder you need to be starting at (e.g. C:\myscripts), it would look like the following:

```
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(1000)
SELECT @sql = 'cd C:\myscripts && sqlcmd -S ' + @@SERVERNAME + ' -d ' + DB_NAME() + ' -i myscript.sql'
EXEC xp_cmdshell @sql
```